# Road to English fluency for advanced speakers

Tags: american-english, esl

I have been learning English all my life. I have been in the US for three years. I consider myself an advanced English speaker. There are many resources on the internet that are geared towards beginners and intermediate English learners. However, I am looking for fluency. I want to be able to speak English as fluently as native English speakers. I guess one problem I have is that I have a good repository of vocabulary that I don't really use when I speak. May be because I am not used to. My vocab repo helps when I am listening or reading but it sometimes fails me when I speak since I dont have much time to think. Can anyone (especially EFL teachers) recommend how to reach fluency especially speaking fluency? and I am not referring to the accent or pronunciation but to the correct usage of vocabulary and correct structuring of sentences.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I suspect the best way to become fluent is just to speak it with natives.

Comment: @Barmar: I do that all the time. I also have an American room mate. I am not sure if that is enough though. It is really hard to assess my improvement (or lack thereof). I am looking for some learning material or a learning process.

Comment: I suspect there's nothing like that. When you learned English, you probably learned proper grammar. But casual speakers don't use proper grammar, there are lots of shortcuts, idioms, etc. There are no guides to this, it's just something we all learn from each other as part of the language community.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning resources (please see [help/on-topic] for details).

Comment: Watch movies. They use natural language and phrases. The more you hear them and notice them in context, the more prone you'll be to use that expression in the proper context. Reading makes better writers and listening makes more fluent speakers. Otherwise  if you are communicating daily with native speakers, ain't much more you can do. Besides memorize poetry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one word: practice.

And in regard to practice, I think you might find [Toastmasters](http://www.toastmasters.org/) very useful.  This organization has branches pretty much everywhere.

Vocabulary is a matter of usage, really.  And of reading.  Most people in any language have a much larger understanding vocabulary than speaking vocabulary.  I find myself sometimes getting tripped up on words -- I might know a word, yes, but suddenly it doesn't come to mind when I need it!  I think everyone has occasions when this happens to them.

And just this: practice.

Comment: I think you re right. Now that I think about it, even in my native language, I can understand a larger set of vocabulary that I can use.

Comment: @Keeto well, it could hardly be the other way around, as that would mean that you were successfully using lots of words that you didn't understand.

Comment: @JonHanna Many of my clients do that.

Comment: @StoneyB do it, or think they do?

Comment: @JonHanna No, actually do it. They utter entire paragraphs of fixed phrases without actually intending any meaning in particular; but because their readers aren't looking for any meaning at all it's entirely successful. I believe political platforms work the same way; and people do get elected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time, take/audit some of the classes in the TEACHING of ESL (e.g., Applied Linguistics/Methods of Teaching ESL/Cross-cultural Communications/Teaching of Reading) offered by many legitimate institutions for teacher re-certification (some might require that you already have at least one [not necessarily in ESL] teaching endorsement, but most will not).

In addition to benefitting from the added practice in an academic setting, the teaching strategies and resources that you will learn about will be applicable/transferable to your goals as a Student of English.

Comment: That's a cool idea!

Comment: What is this symbol you're using for your avatar?  I've seen it everywhere, mostly stuck on cars, but I have no idea what it signifies.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist It's the official logo of "The Human Rights Campaign." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Rights_Campaign  You might have also seen its red/pink version on a lot of Facebook profile pictures back in the Spring of 2013.  RE my answer (glad you liked it, BTW), my wife, a French native, followed that advice and now she's endorsed to teach not only K-12 French (no surprise) but also K-12 ESL here in Virginia.  Another suggestion would be to volunteer as an aide/paraprofessional with a local charitable organization that offers English instruction to those in need of it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for exercises for your special needs. Invent your own methods. But it is not clear to me what you really look for. If you want to advance in using a larger vocabulary and more grammatical structures I think the path to follow is not speaking but writing. Develop your own method of writing daily notes, ten to twenty sentences about topics that interest you. The more and the oftener you write the better your writing will get and it will influence your way of speaking.

Of course, you have to study the problems you face when writing. Problems of vocabulary and of grammar structures. And you have to develop the capacity of solving those problems.